# How to insert emoticons into MySQL using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, unicode, utf-8, utf8mb4

How to insert unicode characters into MySQL and retrieve them using CodeIgniter? Is there any settings to be done.

This is the query when I print it.

```
INSERT INTO `reviews` (`description`) VALUES ('ðŸ˜€')
```

But, it is saving as `????`.

Here is what I have done. CodeIgniter database.php

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8mb4';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

Comment: which Collation type of reviews column you are use in mysql?

Comment: reviews(table) collation : utf8mb4_unicode_ci, description(field) collation is also set to utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: you are using any editor like ckeditor or any else?

Comment: U shud not insert emoticons into the DB. Insert them after utf8_encode of php but doing it directly is not recommended. You can later interpret and change the same during display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine for me when I test it (editor is Sublime Text).

Create MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Run an insert in CI:

```
$this->db->insert('reviews', array('description' => 'ðŸ˜€'));
```

Grab our data back:

```
$result = $this->db->get('reviews');
```

Output our result:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result->row());
echo '</pre>';
```

Our result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [description] => ðŸ˜€
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working, I was just worried about the encrypted data saved into database...it is getting retried well

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

add the following code in database.php

$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8mb4';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';